# What does the "M" button next to the sound and music option do?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Next to the buttons for the option of playing music and the sound option, there is a button with a capital "M". What is this button for?

Comment: Which game are you talking about?

Comment: I'm guessing that would be the **Mute** button

Comment: JetPack Joyride

Comment: I assumed also that is a mute button, & it's possible that it could be and just isn't working on my device (iPhone4 that has been through a lot)!!

Answer (score 3):

The "M" button in the pause menu toggles whether distance markers for your friends are displayed. When the M is active, your Game Center friends' distances will be displayed on markers at those distances in your own game and when inactive, they will not.

I initially found it mentioned [here](http://forums.toucharcade.com/archive/index.php/t-105699-p-7.html) and have tested it myself (although it was quite challenging since I was the one who actually set my friend's high score).

Comment: https://twitter.com/Halfbrick/status/425413358607544320

Comment: So we have halfbrick's confirmation more than a month later. I already tested and confirmed it myself though back when I answered.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that button is made to show the home menu if you wait too long to continue your game, instead of usually continuing said game.